# Cannot assign names into sqlite3 using python

Tags: python, python-2.7, sqlite

I'm new to python and sqlite3.
I'm trying to read data from a csv files and set 
the python to read the name of each coloumn in csv files and assign this name 
to each table or coloumn ( it was set in a loop, so it will read all the names of coloumn and create one table for each name) . But I was running the code following it's having a problem

```
with open(file, 'rb') as f:
    entries = csv.reader(f,delimiter='\t')
    rows= list(entries)
    matrix= numpy.array([])
    result = [0,0,0,0,0]
    for i in range(1,5) :
        a = list(rows[3]) # read the row of each column's name
        a = str(i[c]) # take the first then second till five using loop convert it into string 
        #create a sqlite table named by its coloumn in this case is A 
        c.execute('''create table if not exists ''' + a + ''' (time real, degree0 real, degree45 real, degree90 real, temp real)''') # NEED TO CHANGE TABLE NAME FROM A TO B OR C OR ETC
```

This last line giving a error of AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'execute'.

I was wondering what caused this problem and what should I do?

Comment: Your `c` variable gets reassigned to an integer instead of what it presumbly was earlier in the program, a cursor. Use a different letter for the `for` loop's variable; `i` is a commonly used convention.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing that out. Didn't even realize c has been used before. but now it's having a error saying sqlite3.OperationalError: near "1": syntax error

Comment: I don't have time to test now but you probably can't have a table name start with an integer. You could try repending a letter to the integer.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I just found out the reason it's not working is due to the name i gave to tables are pure number which sqlite3 doesn't accept i assume, and after i change the name back to letters it works fine.

Comment: Consider using sqlalchemy to interact with databases in python

Comment: @RiccardoCagnasso While exploring options isn't a bad idea, I don't see specifically what problems this solves for the OP. To the contrary, in this case, I imagine SQLAlchemy would pose some significant barriers due to the variable table name in the OP's problem. Python's database connection libraries are so simple I'm considering abandoning ORMs entirely with the next project I get a chance to, so unless it solves some specific problems, I don't see a need for it. Very, very, very few practices or tools can be blindly thrown at every problem and consistently result in improved code.